# Importing .obj into Three.js from Blender - Holes missing in Model

Tags: three.js, blender

I am importing a game table in Three JS that I created in Blender and exported in .obj and .mtl files. For some reason the holes that I made in the table using Blenders Bisect tool do not show up when model is exported to Three JS.

Here is the model in Blender:
[image]

Here it is in Three JS:
[image]

Additional info, hopefully it helps:

1. Table surface (in which the holes are cut out) is made from cube mesh object
2. I am receiving no errors in browser console.

Comment: Can you please try it with the more modern `glTF` instead and then use `THREE.GLTFLoader`? The latest Blender version has a  built-in `glTF` importer and exporter.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Tried `THREE.GLTFLoader` and the hole is there! ...but this works even wonkier.. Mirrored sides of the table (I worked on only one quarter of the table, the other 3 quarters are made with Blender Mirror modifier) are gone and also textures do not seem to be loading in. :)